# How to install Akamai and NetStorage CLI on Ubuntu using Docker?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, akamai

I'm trying to set up Akamai and NetStorage CLI on my Ubuntu system using Docker. I want to containerize these tools to ensure a clean and isolated environment for managing Akamai's NetStorage.

Here are my specific requirements:

Dockerized environment for Akamai and NetStorage CLI.
Instructions for installing Akamai and NetStorage CLI within the Docker container.
Proper configuration steps, if needed, to authenticate and use the tools within the container.

I've searched online but couldn't find a clear and comprehensive guide for this setup. Can someone provide step-by-step instructions or a Dockerfile that accomplishes this?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!